# Finding the prefix of multiple classes on an element and switch the prefix to all those

Tags: jquery, html

I have to change the prefix of CSS classes starting with `switchfrom-` to `switchto-`

I got it to work but I am facing an issue where there are two or more classes to the same element starting with `switchfrom-`

The question will be clear when you look at my code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/9as1ddra/4/

The above code changes `switchfrom-div1` and `switchfrom-div2`, but not `switchfrom-mar`

```js
    (function($) {
        $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {
            var funcs = [func1, func2];
            this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
            this.click(function() {
                var data = $(this).data();
                var tc = data.toggleclicked;
                $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
                data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
            });
            return this;
        };
    }(jQuery));
        
    $('button#ToggleUI').clickToggle(function() {   
        var switchfrom = $('[class^="switchfrom-"]');
        switchfrom.each(function(index){
            $(this).attr("class",this.className.replace(/switchfrom-/gi,'switchto-'));
    });
    },
    function() {
        var switchto = $('[class^="switchto-"]');
        switchto.each(function(index){
            $(this).attr("class",this.className.replace(/switchto-/gi,'switchfrom-'));
        });
    });
```

```css
.switchfrom-div1 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#ff0;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
        
.switchfrom-div2 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:white;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
        
.switchto-div1 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:green;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
        
.switchto-div2 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.switch-from-mar {
    margin-left:10px;
}

.switch-to-mar {
    margin-left:0px;
}
.left {
    float:left;
}
        
.right {
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="switchfrom-div1 switch-from-mar left"> test1 </div>
<div class="switchfrom-div2 left"> test2 </div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div class="left">
    <button id="ToggleUI" style="width:200px;height:50px;">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code has "switch-from-mar", not "switchfrom-mar".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$('[class^="switchfrom-"]')` does not target `.switch-from-mar`.

You're looking for classes which start with `switchfrom`, `switch-from-mar` has a `-` between `switch` and `from`.

Change your class to `switchfrom-mar` and it should work. Or if you want to conserve the CSS class then you need to include `switch-from` in your query.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9as1ddra/5/)